# If Loop in Java till condition is no longer valid then continue with script

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, if-statement

I am trying to delete every (visible) row in a table untill there are none left, only then do I want to continue with the rest of my test case. For this reason I'm using an if/else statement. As part of this statement I need to select the first row, click the delete button and then confirm my action by clicking OK. Then I want to go back and check if there is still a first row, if so then repeat till there are no more rows. If not, then press other button. This is what I've got so far:

```
if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='ext-gen445']/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div")) != null) //to determine if there is a first row present
        {
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='ext-gen445']/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div")).click(); // select first row
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@type='button' and text()='Delete']")).click(); //click delete
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("ext-gen483")));

            /** as there is more then one OK button I need the following code to find and click the correct OK button to confirm deleting the row */
            List<WebElement> listOfOKbut = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class=' x-btn-text' and text()='OK']"));
            if(listOfOKbut.size() >= 2) {
                listOfOKbut.get(1).click(); //click OK button to delete
        } // Now I need to back to see if there is a first row again and repeat this till there are no more rows
else{
// Only when there are no more rows do I want to continue
```

Problem now is that when it deletes the first row it skips the else statement and continues with the test script after the else statement, even though there are more rows present.

Also, when I change the first line so that the element cannot be found the script stops completely with a NoSuchElementException. Seems this bit of code is also incorrect.

As some of you may have noticed, I ask a lot of questions. I have not had any Java training (yet) but love what I can do with test automation using this stuff.

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question, but have you tried to use **while()**?

Comment: Get some java training: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/flow.html Questions like this aren't great here because they only solve a very specific for you but won't help others with similar problems (and the problem is essentially not knowing the language)

Comment: This question lacks even the most rudimentary level of the "try to research before you try to ask" concept...

Comment: Where is this influx of programmers, that start from the middle come from? Why do you tackle such complex program, if you did not learn basics yet? Get some good starter book, skim through parts that you already know, but get it.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. i do agree I need training and plan to get this in the near future. In the meanwhile I thought I'd ask here. If this is not the path to walk please let me know. As for the 'research before ask' comment, I do search online for answers before posting here. Allthough this is an awesome place to get questions answered I do try to answer my own questions first. Only when I don't understand the answers found (due to lack of training that I mean to fix) or can't find what I'm looking for I ask my questions here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a while loop, if/else is probably not what you want here

```
    while(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='ext-gen445']/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div")) != null) {
     //element removal code here
   }
   //code you want to run after removing all the elements
```

Comment: Thanks but even though there is still a first row (which was the second row) after deleting the initial first row it skips deleting this and goes on with the rest of the script

Comment: Thank you, this works for the most part. However, even if there are no more rows to delete, it still goes into the removal part of the code and since there is nothing there to select the test case fails there. Apperently my while condition is not good (enough).

Answer (score 1):

First, you do not use a loop construct. Those are `for`, `while` and `do`.

Second, you do use an `if` / `else`. If the fist is true, it never goes into the `else`. That is why it does not run the code you want.

My suggestion is this:

```
While(visible row == true) {
   delete first row
}

// rest of code.
```